# How to log a stack trace whenever Hibernate issues a SQL query?

Tags: sql, hibernate, logging

Log a stack trace in Java:

```
new Throwable.printStackTrace()
```

To see SQL statements issued by Hibernate, [set show_sql to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql).

However, how do I log a stack trace every time a SQL query is issued?  I'd like to use this for performance monitoring (i.e. find which parts of our source code generate the most queries).

I looked at [interceptors and event listeners](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/events.html), and none of them seem to give a hook at the query level.

I also looked through the source (SQLStatementLogger, Loader) somewhat.  I don't see any hooks.

I could perhaps try a [logging jdbc driver](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/), but it's unclear to me if the stack of the caller would be preserved properly.

I could [rewrite byte code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863913/hooking-an-existing-method-in-java), but that seems excessive.

**Edit**: I could also try [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj) to advise the SQL executing methods.

Has anyone done this?  What's the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up attaching a new log Appender to the org.hibernate.SQL logger used by org.hibernate.jdbc.util.SQLStatementLogger (and no other class) in Hibernate 3.6.8.

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate.SQL");
org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender appender =
    new org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender();
appender.setLayout(new SqlLogLayout());
// .. set appender options ..
appender.activateOptions();
logger.addAppender(appender);
```

Then in my SqlLogLayout I can get the stack trace, and the SQL I get from the log message.